# Elastic Search: Is there any way to ignore the script if can't find the document?

Tags: elasticsearch

in following code, I have multiple scripts which some documents could not exist, so currently just update the existing one and return error for non-existing one.
Is there anyway just update the existing one and ignore the rest and return valid status?

```
var script = "new InlineScript($@"if (ctx._source.containsKey('[RemovedField]'))" +
                                              $"{{ ctx._source.remove(\"{RemovedField}\")}}");"

foreach(var update in updates) 
    var operation = new BulkUpdateOperation<IFieldOperation, object>(update.Id)
                {
                    Script = script,
                    ScriptedUpsert = false,
                    //Upsert = don't want upsert if doc not exist 
                    Index = [Index Name]
                };
     operations.Add(operation);

var response = await _client.BulkAsync(new BulkRequest {
                                            Operations = new BulkOperationsCollection<IBulkOperation>(operations)
                                        })

// response.IsValid is equal false which I want to find the way to return as true
```

Comment: Can you clarify your question and giving some examples from your documents and scripts?

Comment: already updated the code above, hope could help you to understand my question

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `noop` operation if the doc doesn't exist

`scripted_upsert` should be set to true so that your script will run regardless if the doc exists or not

then add this line to the script

```
if (ctx._source.isEmpty()) {ctx.op = 'noop'; return}
...<rest of your script follows>
```

In the case you try to update a non-existing doc, `ctx._source` will be empty, then you can just tell elastic to not do anything (noop) and return early

Ps. if `noop` doesn't work, try using `none`, it depends on the es version I think

Comment: thanks Ron, I tried both `noop` & `none` but still get 404 status for non exiting one :(